# Assigning a variable list name when combining two lists in a for loop python

Tags: python

I have two lists in python

```
targetvariables = ['a','b','c']
featurevariables = ['d','e','f']
```

I would like to create three lists such as the following:

```
a_model =  ['a','d','e','f']
b_model = ['b','d','e','f']
c_model = ['c','d','e','f']
```

I have about 15 target variables and 100+ feature variables so is there a way to do this in a loop of some kind? I tried but I couldnt work out how to assign a list name from a changing variable:

```
for idx,target in enumerate(targetvariables):
    target +'_model' = targetvariables[idx] + featurevariables
```

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

The end goal is to test machine learning models and to make things easier I would like to simply call:

```
df[[a_model]]
```

to then use in the ML process.

Comment: One can use a dictionary for this. The key is like the variable name, and the value would be the list.

Comment: any idea how to do this and then how to reference `df[[a_model]]` in that regard? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer: DO NOT DO THIS!

By doing this you're corrupting the global namespace and that's not recommended. If you *really* need to do this, this is how:

```py
for target_var in targetvariables:
    # access the global namespace and modify it
    globals()[f'{target_var}_model'] = [target_var] + featurevariables
```

### Alternative #1

Instead of storing the lists in variables, store them in a container, for example, a `dict`:

```py
models = {}  # create an empty dict
for target_var in targetvariables:
    # the same as the last example but with 'models' instead of 'globals()'
    models[f'{target_var}_model'] = [target_var] + featurevariables
```

Then access the lists like so:

```py
>>> models['a_model']
['a','d','e','f']
```

You can also easly change the code so that the keys of the `dict` would be the variable name itself, without "_model".

### Alternative #2

Instead of storing the lists, create them on the fly with a function:

```py
def get_model(target_var):
    return [target_var] + featurevariables
```

Then access the lists like so:

```py
>>> get_model('a')
['a','d','e','f']
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that are asked literally every day. It makes the site more difficult to navigate.

Comment: So, seriously Use Alternative 1. Having that said you could do this within a functions scope with locals() instead of globals(), but seriously; just enjoy this as a piece of trivia and never use it.

Comment: ah this is great - thanks @Roy!